# refactor large AngularJS module config into separate files

Tags: angularjs

#### Problem: Large `config()`

The config of my AngularJS app is growing quite large. How would you refactor the following into separate files?

```
// app.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
        // Configure routing (uiRouter)
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/site', '/site/welcome');
        $stateProvider.state('main', ...
        ...

        // Configure http interceptors
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {              
            ...
        });
    });
```

---

#### Option 1. Multiple `config()`s

I know that I can have multiple `config()`s and place them in separate files like this:

```
// app.js
angular.module('myApp');

// routerConfiguration.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        // Configure routing (uiRouter)
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/site', '/site/welcome');
        $stateProvider.state('main', ...
        ...

// httpInterceptorConfig.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        // Configure http interceptors
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {              
            ...
        });
    });
```

What I do not like about this, is that in the original app.js, **there is no way of getting an overview** of what is run at startup.

---

#### Option 2. Inject something

I would prefer to do something like this, because it would be easier to see what is configured, directly in the app.js. However I know that this is not possible, since we cannot inject services into `config()`.

**Can I use providers to solve this? Is there a better way?**

```
// app.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function(routerConfig, httpInterceptorConfig) {
        routerConfig.setup();
        httpInterceptorConfig.setup();
    });

// routerConfig.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('routerConfig', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        return {
            setup: function() {
                // Configure routing (uiRouter)
                $urlRouterProvider.when('/site', '/site/welcome');
                $stateProvider.state('main', ...
                ...
            }
        };
    });
});

// httpInterceptorConfig.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('httpInterceptorConfig', function($httpProvider) {
        return {
            setup: function() {
                // Configure http interceptors
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {              
                ...
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you eventually solved this thing using a provider or a constant?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `.constant` as a dependency in a `.config`, so you could use the config declaration as a manual composition root. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider,
                     routerConfig, httpInterceptorConfig) {
        routerConfig($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider);
        httpInterceptorConfig($httpProvider);
    });

// routerConfig.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .constant('routerConfig', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        ...
    });

// httpInterceptorConfig.js
angular.module('myApp')
    .constant('httpInterceptorConfig', function($httpProvider) {          
        ...
    });
```

Drawbacks to this approach are that you have to inject *all* of your config dependencies into the root config function, then manually inject them into your constant config functions. If you have a lot of different config functions, this could get messy. It can also look kind of like your config functions are having dependencies injected by Angular, but in fact you are doing it manually. You would need to make sure you remember to do the manual wiring every time you add a new config function.

My preferred approach is just to have a folder called "config" containing exclusively config calls.

Answer (score 6):

I would look at [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

It allows you to use markup to require modules in your javascript.

This would allow you to break up your `config` into multiple files while keeping them together (see example).

`browserify` compiles your javascript into a single *bundle.js* by recursively tracing the requires from your main javascript file.

You then only need to include `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` on your `index.html`

## Short Example

**Javascript**

```
'use strict';

require('angular/angular');
require('angular-ui/ui-router');

var app = angular.module('vw', ['ui.router', 'myApp.feature1', 'myApp.feature2'])
                 .config(require('./config/route'))
                 .config(require('./config/httpProvider'));

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

**File Structure**

- myApp

  - config

    - route.js
    - httpProvider.js
  - myApp.js
  - index.html

Comment: This was down voted recently, which is fine, but any incite into the reason so I could make adjustments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this recently with a provider.

```
   angular.module('EventView')
.provider('routing', ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        this.init = function() {
            // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

            // Now set up the states
            $stateProvider
                .state('login', {
                    url: '/account/login?{redirectUrl}',
                    controller: 'loginCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/account/login/login.tpl.html'
                })
        }

        // has to be here
        this.$get = function() {
            return {};
        };
    }
]);
```

In the config you can just call the function.

```
angular.module('EventView').config(['routingProvider', function (routingProvider) {
        routingProvider.init();         
    }
]);
```

There are two gotachas, first that the name of the provider adds provider to it when you reference from the config and the second is that you have to implement the $get and return a function.

Good luck!