# Angular ng-controller Issue

Tags: angularjs

Was going through a basic training of AngularJS however get stuck in the first place, with expressions are not evaluating with `ng-controller` dependency.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{"Hello"}}</h1>
        <div ng-controller="StoreController as stores">

          <h1> {{stores.products.name}} </h1>
          <h2> {{stores.products.price}} </h2>
          <p> {{stores.products.description}} </p>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("store", []);
    app.controller = ('StoreController', function () {
        this.products = gem;
    });
    var gem =
        {
            name:'New Product',
            price:'2.95',
            description: 'This is something you would need to buy!!'
        }
})();
```

HTML Output

```
Hello
{{stores.products.name}}
{{stores.products.price}}
{{stores.products.description}}
```

Please help me what mistake I have done.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Sorry which IDE I should use this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an = sign in your controller that is incorrect.

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("store", []);
    ////NOT app.controller = ('StoreController'.....
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        this.products = gem;
    });
    var gem =
        {
            name:'New Product',
            price:'2.95',
            description: 'This is something you would need to buy!!'
        }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks oops, dint pay attention. Good eyes. However any IDE I can use?

Comment: I use sublime text and I'm trying webstorm right now, both are solid IDEs

Comment: But if you check the `console` log in the browser, hit `f12` in chrome for example and you would have seen an error that `StoreController` is not a function.

Comment: You could also define it as `StoreController = function () {this.products = gem;};`   . Is this in sync with best practices, or not?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos defining the controller function in that fashion makes the controller function available in the `global` scope (not a good thing).  If you are interested in modularizing more, I use browserify [take look at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424074/refactor-large-angularjs-module-config-into-separate-files/25424635#25424635)

Answer (score 2):

It is more typical and I would say best practice to set any data on `$scope`. Then you don't have to use the alias for your controller and reference products simply. You would have to inject `$scope` into your controller. The code would look like:

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{"Hello"}}</h1>
        <div ng-controller="StoreController">

          <h1> {{products.name}} </h1>
          <h2> {{products.price}} </h2>
          <p> {{products.description}} </p>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("store", []);
    app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.products = gem;
    }]);
    var gem =
        {
            name:'New Product',
            price:'2.95',
            description: 'This is something you would need to buy!!'
        }
})();
```

Comment: When working with larger applications there are advantages to using an alias for the controller because it is clear which scope you are working with in the view.

Comment: Thanks guys, Let me try it. So my usage with alias is wrong?

Comment: This actually won't fix your problem you have a syntax error.

Comment: Oh yeah. And I managed to copy that to my answer too. Fixed it. I hope my answer at least removed some confusion with the aliasing which is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Pay attention to [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) vs [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

You want to set the ng-controller attribute to the controller name and in a different attribute ng-repeat for repeating the data.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the persons question.