# How to include angular service and controller files dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

I want to make service and controller in seperate files but I don't want to load those scripts all time in index.html. If I have 20 controllers and 20 services, I need to write 40 lines of script tag in index html to be able to use services and controllers in angular. How can I load them without writing too many script tags in index.html? Am I wrong to seperate those files?

Sorry for not good English.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to dynamically load js. In this situation you shouldn't be doing it, because of issues where Directives/Templates can be marked as `compiled` . If you dont not want 40 script tags you should bundle your scripts

Comment: Angular just made a lot more sense to me with this comment. So then there's no trouble with minifying 1000 scripts to one, caching it, and only including that one script on every page (because the page behaviors will be defined by ng controller attributes)

Comment: I use browserify myself for exactly this. [Related Question about  organizing angular App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424074/refactor-large-angularjs-module-config-into-separate-files/25424635#25424635)

Comment: @katana314 Correct (in regards to minifying all our scripts into 1 include). I do not understand the comment `and only including that one script on every page`. You should only have 1 page and inside that page have an ng-view tag. Then your views should change inside that ng-view tag within that 1 page, so you should only need 1 include statement

Comment: @gh9 Realistically, some of the sites I've worked on would have multiple pages with some shared, some not-shared behaviors, even when a majority of functionality can be asynchronous. But, as a newbie to angular, the comment about `ng-view` is helpful too.